# Find out the quarter based on the financial year in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables, one is `Period` and the other is `UserTarget`.

`Period` table is:

```
QuarterNo      StartDate    EndDate
-----------------------------------------
   1           2018-04-01   2018-06-30
   2           2018-07-01   2018-09-30
   3           2018-10-01   2018-12-31
   4           2019-01-01   2019-03-31
```

`UserTarget` table is :

```
USERID    YEAR    QTR    AMOUNT
---------------------------------
akshay    2019     1      200
```

Right now I am taking the qtr no from period table. Now I don't need take qtr no from period table. I want it from stored procedure based on year is entered in `usertarget` table

Existing stored procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetQuarterlyTargetData]
    @Userid VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @QuarterNumber VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @SetTarget DECIMAL(10);
    DECLARE @StartDate DATE
    DECLARE @EndDate DATE

    SELECT
        @QuarterNumber = p.QuarterNo,
        @SetTarget = AMOUNT 
    FROM 
        PERIOD p 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        USERTARGETS s ON p.QuarterNo = s.QTR  
    WHERE
        StartDate <= GETDATE() AND EndDate >= GETDATE() 

    SELECT
        @StartDate = StartDate,
        @EndDate = EndDate 
    FROM 
        PERIOD 
    WHERE
        QuarterNo = @QuarterNumber
```

From this procedure I am getting the start date and end date for quarter but I don't want to modify in period table every time when I want to check previous years data.

Comment: Hi i thin you have to add some year control too the second query , like this : case when month(getdate) > 3 then year = year(getdate)+1 else year = year(getdate)  end

Comment: @pascalsanchez I deleting the period table now I have only user target table and in this I have year based on that I have to modify my procedure

Comment: it’s ok in this case, have a nice day

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask.   Can you get a native English speaker to help you re-write your question?   It doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking I come up to this solutions

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[Dashboard_GetQuarterlyTargetData]
    @Userid varchar(50)

    AS
    Begin 
         DECLARE @QuarterNumber varchar(50)
         DECLARE @SetTarget decimal(10);
         DECLARE @AchievedTarget decimal(10);
         DECLARE @TargetProgress decimal(10);
         DECLARE @RemainingTarget decimal(10);
         DECLARE @StartDate Date
         DECLARE @EndDate Date
         DECLARE @Year as int

        Select @QuarterNumber = QTR,@Year=YEAR,@SetTarget=AMOUNT from  USERTARGETS  where USERID=@Userid 

        if(@QuarterNumber = 1)
        begin
          SELECT @StartDate = DATEFROMPARTS(@year,4,1), @EndDate=DATEFROMPARTS(@year,6,30)
        End
        else if(@QuarterNumber = 2)
        begin
         SELECT @StartDate = DATEFROMPARTS(@year,7,1), @EndDate=DATEFROMPARTS(@year,9,30)
        End
        else if(@QuarterNumber = 3)
        begin
         SELECT @StartDate = DATEFROMPARTS(@year,10,1), @EndDate=DATEFROMPARTS(@year,12,31)
        End
        else if(@QuarterNumber = 4)
        begin
         SELECT @StartDate = DATEFROMPARTS(@year,1,1), @EndDate=DATEFROMPARTS(@year,3,31)
        End
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the term you are looking for is fiscal year. It's where the company year is different than the calendar year.

Note that many people recommend using a lookup table instead of calculating it. Date matches can be difficult for SQL to optimize.

Here's one way to do it. Finding the fiscal year and quarter would probably be good to put in a table function.

```
DECLARE @userTarget TABLE (UserId VARCHAR(20), Year INT, Quarter INT, Amount INT)
INSERT INTO @userTarget
VALUES
    ('akshay', 2018, 4, 150)
    ,('akshay', 2019, 1, 200)

SELECT
    s.UserId
    ,s.Amount
    ,FY.FiscalYear
    ,FQ.FiscalQuarter
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            --DATEFROMPARTS(2019, 2, 23) 
            GETDATE()
                AS reportDate
    ) AS ReportDate
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            CASE WHEN MONTH(ReportDate.reportDate) < 4 THEN YEAR(ReportDate.reportDate) - 1 -- Fiscal Year begins in April
                ELSE YEAR(ReportDate.reportDate)
            END AS FiscalYear
    ) AS FY
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            DATEDIFF(QUARTER, DATEFROMPARTS(FY.FiscalYear, 4, 1), ReportDate.reportDate) + 1 AS FiscalQuarter
    ) AS FQ
    INNER JOIN @userTarget s
        ON s.Year = FY.FiscalYear
            AND s.Quarter = FQ.FiscalQuarter
```

Also, be careful with end dates. `last_day >= GETDATE()` does not include the last day. Take as an example the end of last quarter, it would calculate it as `'2019-03-31 00:00' >= '2019-03-31 08:20'` which is false when you want it to be true.